# Ranch Listener Error failed on phoenix websocket implementation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I have implemented websocket to my phoenix app. Before it success to connected and joined room to my websocket, but right now i got this error:

```
error] Ranch listener MarketPlaceDisbursementServiceWeb.Endpoint.HTTP had connection process 
started with :cowboy_clear:start_link/4 at #PID<0.499.0> exit with reason: {%Jason.DecodeError
{data: "{   \"topic\": \"room:marketplace_disbursement_service\",   \"event\": \"inquiry_response\", 
  \"payload\": {},   \"ref\": 0 }", position: 2, token: nil}, [{Jason, :decode!, 2, [file: 'lib/jason.ex', line: 78]}, {Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, :decode!, 2, [file: 'lib/phoenix/socket/serializers/v1_json_serializer.ex',
 line: 29]}, {Phoenix.Socket, :__in__, 2, [file: 'lib/phoenix/socket.ex', line: 498]}, '{Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler, :websocket_handle, 2, [file: 'lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex', line: 77]}, {:cowboy_websocket, :handler_call, 6, [file: 
'/Users/jaisanas/work/backend/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_websocket.erl', line: 471]}, {:cowboy_http, :loop,
 2, [file: '/Users/jaisanas/work/backend/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_http.erl', line: 233]}, {:proc_lib, 
:init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}
```

and here is my mix.exs file:

```
{:phoenix, "~> 1.4.0"},
{:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
{:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
{:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
{:jason, "~> 1.0"},
{:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
{:httpoison, "~> 1.4"},
{:poison, "~> 3.1"}
```

On this thread [github](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/3222) said that i have to delete `rm -rf _build`. But it still returns error, how to solve this?

Comment: Please put `IO.inspect()` in `'lib/phoenix/socket.ex'` right before the line `498`, dump the payload and post it here.

Comment: i cannot find that file

Comment: that is lib file

Comment: So what? Dump the payload from there, otherwise, it’s divination on coffee grounds.